# Actualizar App Android de JDK 11 a JDK 17

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Tengo una App Android que actualmente utiliza JDK 11, estoy actualizando a JDK 17. Soy nuevo en el desarrollo móvil y tengo dudas si esta actualización de JDK vaya a tener algún impacto no deseado, por ejemplo que la App deje de ser compatible con algunos dispositivos. Si alguien tiene conocimiento de esto agradecería sus comentarios. Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega más información, que versión de Android Studio usas y tu archivo Build.gradle por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Desde Android Studio Flamingo Canary 3 el IDE de Android Studio viene con JDK 17, tal y como se dice en [este enlace](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-flamingo-release-notes?hl=es-419):

> #### Android Studio incluido con el JDK 17
>
> A partir de Android Studio Flamingo Canary 3, el IDE de Studio se
> incluye con el JDK 17. Si Android Studio está configurado para usar el
> JDK incorporado, los proyectos nuevos usarán la versión estable más
> reciente del complemento de Android para Gradle y JDK 17. Sin embargo,
> los proyectos existentes pueden fallar, y es posible que debas
> configurar el JDK en una versión compatible de forma manual.

La misma nota dice que *los proyectos existentes pueden fallar*, en cuyo caso deberás configurar el JDK a una versión compatible. Pero ese fallo difícilmente sea debido a compatibilidad con un determinado dispositivo. La incompatibilidad en este caso podría ser más bien con respecto al código. Es decir, que en tu App uses código no compatible u obsoleto con respecto a JDK 17.

Simplemente, configura a JDK 17 y luego prueba tu proyecto. Si falla, puedes configurar el JDK a una versión compatible con el mismo o bien (y esta sería la mejor opción) actualiza ese código Java antiguo que hace que tu proyecto no sea compatible con JDK 17.

Ten en cuenta que si usas Gradle, debes revisar también la [matriz de compatibilidad](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), de la cual deducimos lo siguiente para tu caso:

- Si vas a usar JDK 17, debes usar al menos Gradle 7.3 o superior.
- Si tu proyecto no fuera compatible y estás usando una versión muy antigua de JDK, considera que desde Gradle 9 los tests no serán soportados si usas JDK 6 y 7. Lo mejor de lo mejor es poder tener todo actualizado a la última versión compatible, si es posible.